# Hadamard product derivative

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

If $\circ$ represents the Hadamard product, and $^*$ the conjugate-transpose operation. Given

$$f_{(\mathbf{x})} =(\mathbf{x} \circ \mathbf{x})^*H(\mathbf{x} \circ \mathbf{x}) - (\mathbf{x} \circ \mathbf{x})^*\mathbf{y}$$
$H$ is Hermitian, $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are complex-valued.

How can we obtain the derivative of $f_{(\mathbf{x})}$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) treats $x$ and $x^*$ independently, so that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x\circ \bar H(\bar x\circ\bar x)$